# Get editorWidgetV2 type and config from field index

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes

I want to duplicate properties of fields (widget, type, lenght etc.)

I cannot figure out why when I try to get the widget value, I always get **TextEdit** widget type and no configuration. I changed it under layer properties but no change appear on log. How can I get the properties value I have set ?

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

##input_layer=vector
##field_to_duplicate=field input_layer


layer=QgsVectorLayer(input_layer, "tmpName", 'ogr')    
pr = layer.dataProvider()    
caps = pr.capabilities()

fields = layer.pendingFields()

for field in fields:
    if field.name() == field_to_duplicate:
        FieldIdx = fields.indexFromName(field.name()) 
        field_widget = layer.editorWidgetV2(FieldIdx)
        field_widgetConfig = layer.editorWidgetV2Config(FieldIdx)   
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str(FieldIdx)+str(field_widget)+str(field_widgetConfig), tag="Processing", level=QgsMessageLog.INFO)
```

here the message log output :

```
5TextEdit{}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not applying the changes to the **loaded layer** as you are using:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer(input_layer, "tmpName", 'ogr')
```

Because you are referencing the shapefile itself, all fields are read as default which is `Text Edit`.

Instead, use:

```
layer = processing.getObject(input_layer)
```

This should give you the correct widget information.

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa-GeoDatup - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Add little example using @joseph suggestion.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
import processing

##input_layer=vector
##field_to_duplicate=field input_layer

layer = processing.getObject(input_layer)

for field_index, field in enumerate(layer.pendingFields()):
    if field.name() == field_to_duplicate:
        field_widget = layer.editorWidgetV2(field_index)
        field_widgetConfig = layer.editorWidgetV2Config(field_index)   
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str(FieldIdx)+str(field_widget)+str(field_widgetConfig), tag="Processing", level=QgsMessageLog.INFO)
```

and result is correct.

```
0TextEdit{}
1TextEdit{}
2TextEdit{}
3TextEdit{}
4Hidden{}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. I prefer give the answer "checked" to Joseph cause he gave the solution. But many thanks for go deeper on this. ;)

Comment: your welcome!!!